# What was the token Kurumi was given before her duel supposed to mean?

Tags: shinmai-mao-no-testament

During the tournament, when it is her turn to fight against the scythe demon, he gives Kurumi a yellow round token she immediately links to Basara, and begins to worry about him, to the point her fighting skill is impaired and she loses the duel.

What is that token supposed to mean?

Comment: i believe it was a button

Comment: I remember it was something with spell on it to distract her from the fight, but couldn't get a good proofs/ links about it. Though i believe there was this scene right after that fight that they(her team) reacted like *so that is why she lost* reaction, like the enemy is playing dirty or something.

Comment: let me clarify... its a [coat button](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/3uhvxi/spoilers_shinmai_maou_no_testament_burst_episode/cxf0ycp)